# Alternatives to using food coloring for kids activities

Tags: activities, arts-and-crafts

We do a lot of activities that seem to use food coloring in our house - making play doh, playing with colored vinegar and baking soda, etc. Food coloring seems to be pretty pricey in our local grocery stores, though - $4 or $5 for one of those little boxes with the 4 colors.

What other choices do I have? How can add color to things without expensive food coloring?

Comment: Cool, I'd love to hear about some of your activities.  I'm always looking for more.

Comment: Seems a bit offtopic, as a shopping question - it will be localised in time and country, I would imagine.

Comment: I've now rephrased the question to avoid being a shopping recommendation. This even made existing answers more applicable! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [making your own](http://fromscratchclub.com/2011/12/13/from-scratch-holidays-diy-natural-food-coloring/)? Some colors are really easy to make (yellow=turmeric powder, red=beets, etc.) but other colors are not too bad either. You avoid using too many chemicals/by products and it iss CHEAP! (1 cup of produce = 4oz of food coloring)

Comment: Yes. There's an extensive list [here](http://www.pioneerthinking.com/crafts/crafts-basics/naturaldyes.html)

Comment: @bobobobo, that's a wonderful list!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you can find food coloring in bulk, but a good replacement for food coloring in almost any craft that calls for it, is liquid watercolor.  The extra advantage is you have more color options this way.  Here is a link to a discount supply company that sells liquid watercolors.  I have never seen them on a store shelf, but they can be ordered through this [link](http://www.discountschoolsupply.com/product/productdetail.aspx?product=16821).  Or go to discountschoolsupply.com and do a search for "liquid watercolor".